# SHGetSpecialFolderPath to a System::String^

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, appdata, tchar

I'm trying to parse a `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` into a string, a `System::String^` to be precise.
I'm now using this code:

```
TCHAR appDataPath;
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, appDataPath, CSIDL_APPDATA, false);
```

I've tried things like this, but it doesn't work either:

```
LPWSTR appDataPath;
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, appDataPath, CSIDL_APPDATA, false);
```

I just want to get a `System::String^` like this:

```
System::String ^ loc_inst = appDataPath + "\\inst\\info.xml";
```

Comment: Use Environment::GetFolderPath() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think C++/CLI can automatically concatenate char arrays and assign them to a string handle.  I think you need to instantiate a new `System::String` object like this:

```
System::String^ loc_inst = gcnew System::String(appDataPath);
loc_inst.Append("\\inst\\info.xml");
```

Or you could use a `StringBuilder`, but if you want to make a new `String` object I think you've got to use `gcnew` and a constructor.

Keep in mind that `appDataPath` is not a `String` but a char array that you have previously allocated.  However, `System::String` allows you to pass in char arrays in one of its constructors.

Comment: Ah, thank you, code now:

StringBuilder^ build_str = gcnew StringBuilder("", MAX_PATH);   
for (int i = 0; i < appDataPath[MAX_PATH]; i++)
{
 build_str->Append(gcnew array<Char>{appDataPath[i]});
}
System::String^ loc_inst = build_str->ToString();